# hi im a bit new into laravel and php i got this error [InvalidArgumentException]

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

[InvalidArgumentException]Invalid scheduled callback event. Must be string or callable.
this is the code

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();
   $schedule->call($this->consult());
}

/**
 * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function consult()
{//try {
    $url=DB::table('remote_services')->pluck('url');
   foreach ($url as $url){
       echo $url;
       echo  '   ';}
//}catch (InvalidArgumentException $e ){
  //  echo 'captured exception';
}
```

Comment: You're provided line numbers with your error, as well as a stack trace. Both  would be incredibly useful in helping debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you've passed wrong type of parameter into the `call` method, for example, you've this:

```
$schedule->call($this->consult());
```

Here, you've actually, called the `$this->consult()` method and passed the result; which is equivalent to this:

```
$methodCallResult = $this->consult();
$schedule->call($methodCallResult);
```

But, the call method here, actually accepts either a `Callable` or a `String`. In case of `String` the string could be `SomeClass@methodName` or `SomeClass::staticMethodName`.

In case of callable, it could be either a `Closure/Anonymous Function` or an instance method like `[$anObject, 'someMethod']` and in your case it could be the following:

```
// Call the consult method of same/this class
$schedule->call([$this, 'consult']);
```

Also, in this case, your `consult` method should <strike>(probably, not sure exactly, so try protected first)</strike> be `public` instead of `protected`.